# Libpcap issues with release build C++ application

Tags: c++, xcode, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I've developed a network sonification app in C++ that uses libpcap for packet capture. It works fine on my computer (early 2012 Macbook) but when I try to run the release build application on any other machine libpcap can't open a handle and returns null. I've added a post-build script in Xcode that adds the libpcap .dylibs from my usr/libs folder to a Frameworks folder in the application contents so they should be accessible but I can't figure out why libpcap is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Run the command `ls -l /dev/bpf*` on your computer and on the other computer and add the results to your question.  If they show different ownership or permissions on the BPF devices, that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: "I've added a post-build script in Xcode that adds the libpcap .dylibs from my usr/libs folder" Is there some reason why you're not just using the libpcap that comes as part of OS X?